# How does typescript resolve @types/<projectFolder>?

Tags: typescript

In the [Handbook article about module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules), it is described, that for e.g. `import { name } from 'moduleB';`, it looks for `/root/node_modules/@types/moduleB.d.ts` (among others). When i check, the `@types` folder typically has package folders, not files. However, it works - the compiler is apparently looking into these package folders. It resolves the correct `root/node_modules/@types/moduleB/index.d.ts`.

Is there some other rule, by which tsc checks the package folders of `node_modules/@types`? Is there some inaccuracy in the description by the handbook, or is it just me misunderstanding something?

I realize, that `node_modules/@types` seems to be special in other ways. E.g. by default, without clearing the `compilerOptions` for `types`, or `typeRoots`, that global declarations from `./node_modules/@types` would get included. To me, this still doesn't explain, why it finds the "proper" definitions for a package import, when by documentation, it should never look into the folders for those.

Comment: Types resolution attempts to match several different package layout and naming conventions. You can observe this by running `tsc --noEmit --traceResolution` in your project. At any rate, the behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks. To me, it looked like the handbook article tried to offer an exhaustive list of all attempts, but it is not? Is there any complete description of where and what it looks for?